# How do you prevent expo from using devDependencies?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, expo

I have a project where I put a React Context code into a local module and included it using

```
nom install directory
```

The `package.json` itself has the following

```
  "devDependencies": {
    "@types/react": "^16.14.2",
    "@typescript-eslint/eslint-plugin": "^4.14.0",
    "@typescript-eslint/parser": "^4.14.0",
    "axios": "^0.21.1",
    "eslint": "^7.18.0",
    "eslint-plugin-prettier": "^3.3.1",
    "expo-secure-store": "^10.0.0",
    "prettier": "2.2.1",
    "react": "^16.13.1",
    "react-native": "^0.63.4",
    "typedoc": "^0.20.19",
    "typedoc-plugin-mermaid": "^1.3.0",
    "typescript": "^4.1.3"
  },
  "peerDependencies": {
    "axios": "axios^0.17.0 || axios^0.19.0 || ^0.21.1",
    "expo-secure-store": "^9.0.0 || ^10.0.0",
    "react-native": "^0.62.0 || ^0.63.0"
  },
  "dependencies": {},
```

What happens is if I install the local module, Expo will be building it and at runtime there would be two Reacts.

My workaround for now is to do a `npm prune --production` on the folder. Is there some sort of setting I am missing so I can avoid having to do the workaround?